# Python, Use global var from function in other .py file / NameError

Tags: python, import, global-variables, nameerror

*get_asset_type_v001.py*

```
import re

def get_asset_type(filename):
    """Check filename for asset type"""
    global is_vfx_file, is_edit_file, proj_yy, client, show, edit_version, edit_stage, tv, pv, date, seq_nr, seq_name, shot_nr, shot_name
    is_vfx_file = False
    is_edit_file = False
    if re.match(edit_pattern, filename):  # Check if file is a edit prev
        print("\nFile is an Edit prev. Filename: {}".format(filename))
        proj_yy, client, show, edit_version, edit_stage, tv, pv, date, *_ = filename.split("_")
        is_edit_file = True
    if re.match(vfx_pattern, filename):  # Check if file is a VFX prev
        print("\nFile is a VFX prev. Filename: {}".format(filename))
        seq_nr, seq_name, shot_nr, shot_name, *_ = filename.split("_")
        is_vfx_file = True

# get_asset_type(sample_vfx_filename) # Call function to return is vfx file and print result
# print(is_vfx_file)  # Check if it's a vfx file
```

Printing the function in the same file works like charm.

```
print('_'.join(list((seq_nr, seq_name, shot_nr, shot_name))))
```

*main_programm_file_v001.py*

```
from get_asset_type_v001 import *  # Import function ti check what asset type it is


filename = sample_vfx_filename

get_asset_type(filename)  # Code workes fine till this line
print('_'.join(list((seq_nr, seq_name, shot_nr, shot_name))))  # The variables in this line "seq_nr..." are making the problem
```

But trying to use the code from the imported function in another file raises the following error. Seems like I can't access the global var.

**NameError: name 'seq_nr' is not defined**

Comment: `seq_nr` is only defined if `re.match(vfx_pattern, filename)` succeeds. Did it? Check the value of `is_vfx_file`.

Comment: On another note, don't use so many global variables. `get_asset_type` should return an object that encapsulates the information returned by `filename.split("_")`.

Comment: NameError: name 'is_vfx_file' is not defined

Comment: So no variable gets through .. :/

Comment: They weren't defined at the time you imported the module (they are only created when you call the function), and even if they were, there is a difference between the local name `is_vfx_file` in `main_programm_file_v001.py` imported from the module and `is_vfx_file.seq_nr` itself.

Comment: why is_vfx_file.seq_nr don't you mean is_vfx_file.get_asset_type_v001

Comment: Yes; another reason to avoid using globals from other modules: the names get too long to keep straight :)

Comment: How would I approach this, if I don't use globals? I mean I need to have a function that returns a lot of values that are defined within that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would redefine the function to return a value that includes metadata about what type of filename was passed. One example:

```
import re

def get_asset_type(filename):
    """Check filename for asset type"""
    if re.match(edit_pattern, filename):
        print("\nFile is an Edit prev. Filename: {}".format(filename))
        fields = filename.split("_")
        return {'type': 'edit',
                'proj_yy': fields[0],
                'client': fields[1],
                ...}
    if re.match(vfx_pattern, filename):  # Check if file is a VFX prev
        print("\nFile is a VFX prev. Filename: {}".format(filename))
        fields = filename.split("_")
        return {'type': 'vfx',
                'seq_nr': fields[0],
                'seq_name': fields[1],
                ...}
```

It's likely that your regular expressions can be defined using capture groups to avoid the need to subsequently split the file name; if the pattern matches, the return value will already contain the relevant components.

Then in your main program:

```
import get_asset_type_v001

filename = sample_vfx_filename

result = get_asset_type_v001.get_asset_type(filename)
if result['type'] == 'vfx':
    print('_'.join([result['seq_nr'], result['seq_name'], ...]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your approach. It's actually the first one that seems to work! I appreciate all your effort that went into this. 
Two more questions regarding this. Isn't `Return` the same thing as `Global` just a different way to return it? And secondly, you wrote I should use capture groups. So I read my way through them and used them. But I'm not sure if it makes the code easier to write or to understand, even if it is an interesting approach. I've written my code with the capture groups below. Thanks again.

Comment: `return` and `global` are completely different. Returning a value makes no assumptions about what variables are or will be defined outside of the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

option with capture groups:

```
def get_asset_type(filename): # V003
    """Check filename for asset type"""
    n = re.match(edit_pattern, filename)
    if n:  # Check if file is a edit prev
        print("\nFile is an Edit prev. Filename: {}".format(filename))
        fields = filename.split("_")
        return {'type': 'edit',
                'proj_yy': n.group('proj_yy'),
                'client': n.group('client'),
                'show': n.group('show'),
                'edit_version': n.group('edit_version'),
                'edit_stage': n.group('edit_stage'),
                'tv': n.group('tv'),
                'pv': n.group('pv'),
                'date': n.group('date'),
                }
    m = re.match(vfx_pattern, filename)
    if m:  # Check if file is a VFX prev
        print("\nFile is a VFX prev. Filename: {}".format(filename))
        print(m.group('seq_name'))
        return {'type': 'vfx',
                'seq_nr': m.group('seq_nr'),
                'seq_name': m.group('seq_name'),
                'shot_nr': m.group('shot_nr'),
                'shot_name': m.group('shot_name')
                }
```